# Error: Python module 'cleannlp' not found. Install with: pip install cleannlp in R

Tags: r, ubuntu, rstudio

I am using R studio, on ubuntu 18.4, specifically the cleannlp package to analyze texts according to [this tutorial found here https://statsmaths.github.io/cleanNLP/state-of-union.html](https://statsmaths.github.io/cleanNLP/state-of-union.html).

As per the installation instructions found [here - https://statsmaths.github.io/cleanNLP/](https://statsmaths.github.io/cleanNLP/), I have thus far installed cleannlp like thus `install.packages("cleanNLP")` in Rstudio's console. Further, I have install it's modules `pip install cleannlp` in terminal. As far as I can see, I have not had any trouble with either installation.

There are 4 backends to cleannlp as evidenced in the installation instructions:

```
cnlp_init_stringi(locale="en_GB")
cnlp_init_udpipe(model_name="english")
cnlp_init_spacy(model_name="en")
cnlp_init_corenlp(lang="en")
```

I do not seem to have any trouble using stringi or udpipe. However, using spacy and corenlp backends seem to be throwing this error

```
Error: Python module 'cleannlp' not found. Install with: pip install cleannlp
4. stop(msg, call. = (msg == ""))
3. assert(!is.null(disc$required_module_path), "Python module 'cleannlp' not found. Install with:\n pip install cleannlp")
2. check_python()
1. cnlp_init_spacy("/usr/local/lib/python3.6/")
```

I am fairly certain the python package is installed successfully, inferring this from the following:

```
(base) redapemusic35@mythinker:~$ pip install cleannlp
Processing ./.cache/pip/wheels/1e/23/e6/a201f9e10a6664d0639453ee4f19bba7baf8544e9e82b18d1b/cleannlp-1.0.3-py3-  none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: spacy in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from cleannlp) (2.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: plac<1.2.0,>=0.9.6 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spacy->cleannlp) (1.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spacy->cleannlp) (45.2.0.post20200210)
Requirement already satisfied: srsly<1.1.0,>=0.1.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spacy->cleannlp) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: blis<0.5.0,>=0.4.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spacy->cleannlp) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spacy->cleannlp) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.15.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spacy->cleannlp) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: thinc<7.4.0,>=7.3.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spacy->cleannlp) (7.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.4.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spacy->cleannlp) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spacy->cleannlp) (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spacy->cleannlp) (3.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spacy->cleannlp) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from spacy->cleannlp) (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from thinc<7.4.0,>=7.3.0->spacy->cleannlp) (4.42.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy->cleannlp) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy->cleannlp) (1.25.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy->cleannlp) (2019.11.28)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy->cleannlp)(3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=0.20; python_version< "3.8" in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7->spacy->cleannlp) (1.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=0.20; python_version < "3.8"->catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7->spacy->cleannlp) (2.2.0)
Installing collected packages: cleannlp
Successfully installed cleannlp-1.0.3
```

Some things I have tried include

1. no path in 
   `cnlp_init_spacy()`

Which gives me:

```
Error: Python module 'cleannlp' not found. Install with: pip install cleannlp
4. stop(msg, call. = (msg == ""))
3.
assert(!is.null(disc$required_module_path), "Python module 'cleannlp' not found. Install with:\n pip install cleannlp")
2. check_python()
1. cnlp_init_spacy()
```

no difference whether I this with either of the backends (both spacy and corenlp) giving me trouble.

2. `sudo pip install 
   sudo -H pip install
   sudo -H pip3 install`

   and

   `sudo pip3 install`

   All of which seem to work fine. I wonder however, if there is a problem with R choosing which installation. So I uninstalled and tried again. Further, I do seem to have any trouble with python outside of R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that R is using a python environment that doesn't have "cleannlp" installed. You can check this via:

```
install.packages("reticulate")
library(reticulate)
py_discover_config(required_module="cleannlp")
```

This should point to your anaconda3 path. In case it is pointing to another environment, e.g. r-miniconda, you can change this with:

```
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = path)
```

where path is you path to anaconda, which in Mac often has the form: "/Users/YOUR_NAME/anaconda3/bin/python"

Now run:

```
py_discover_config(required_module="cleannlp")
```

again and check if it does find "cleannlp" in your anaconda3 python environment.
If that worked, then you can now run:

```
cnlp_download_corenlp()
cnlp_init_corenlp(lang="en")
```